# CSS proportional transform (scale) of div including text, images to fit width

Tags: html, css, svg

For marketing banners, etc. it is desirable to keep the precise look of a page (or part thereof). That means all the margins, text sizes, image sizes, etc. The simplest way to do this is to use absolute XY positioning for each element, and then scale entire aggregate block (parent element) to fit the width of the device.

Rationale: Layouts like flexbox require a lot of tweaking to get "just right" and assumes that text size should be fixed as the device size changes. In reality, scaling the text with the device makes sense in many case (within a device category, like smartphones).  At the same time, it's good to have the text in HTML, as opposed to exporting as an image (for SEO)

Is this possible to do with CSS? I have not found a resource on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this kind of layout can be accomplished by using a foundation of [viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) (`vw` or `vh` units) so that your page scales based on the size of your browser window.

All you really need to make this work is to start your CSS with a viewport-percentage unit as the `font-size` of a root element (`body`, `:root`, or a wrapper div), and then style everything inside using `em` units - which will be based on the browser size.

One thing to keep in mind is that `em` units cascade based on the closest parent element with a `font-size` specified, so if you want a property to be sized based on the root `1vw` without fonts affecting it, use `rem` units to size relative to the root.

Here's a very rudimentary example of a layout that will grow/shrink depending on the window width, but maintain its exact layout and positioning regardless.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  flex: 0 0 20rem;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.side ul {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.side img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20rem;
  width: 16rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 80rem;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side">
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet felis vitae nulla efficitur mattis. Nulla cursus lectus ut libero molestie, in elementum dolor faucibus. Vivamus pretium pulvinar maximus. Quisque erat nunc, aliquet at eros id,
    ultricies placerat dui. Nullam pellentesque euismod ligula, non viverra quam ullamcorper vel. Ut feugiat est ut felis consequat tempus. Aenean molestie mauris eget turpis tincidunt, a dictum orci malesuada. Maecenas semper interdum nulla, quis gravida
    quam accumsan nec. Nunc gravida, eros in cursus vehicula, erat dolor porttitor tellus, ac congue felis ante non metus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works great on its own, but when I try to insert into my app it doesn't work anymore, maybe I haven't found the right place to add the "root" style.  I tried adding it in the parent div, the top div (I'm using styled-components, and also don't want to break other things).  I tried adding  &:root { or :root { font-size: 1vw; } inside a styled-component.  Nothing worked.  Do you have any other hacks for this left up your sleeve?

Comment: I can't help without seeing your code - but either way, this is a methodology for building a layout from scratch and not something you'd be able to shoehorn into an existing page unless you manually converted all of your units from `px` to `em` and `rem` once you've implemented the root `vw` rule.